# Capturing the output of a ASP template for unittesting

Tags: asp-classic

I'm trying to find a way to capture the response of ASP templates for testing purposes. After reading [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/18/how-does-active-server-pages-use-the-script-engines.aspx) post i was hoping that the following code would provide a solution:

```
class cMockResponse
    public data
    public sub write( value)
        if isempty(data) then data = ""
        data = data & value
    end sub
end class

class cView
    public response
    private sub class_initialize()
        set response = new cMockResponse
    end sub
    public sub render()
      ' expected that the following would be compiled to response.write "hello world"
      %> hello world <% 
    end sub        
end class

set view = new cView
call view.render()
response.write "the mock respone was:" & view.response.data
```

Given the blog post i hoped that

```
%> hello world <%
```

would be simply translated to

```
response.write "hello world"
```

Since response references the mock object I hoped that this solution would do the trick, but clearly it doesn't. The output of the above code is unsurprisingly:

```
hello world the mock response was:
```

Are there other methods to capture the output of ASP templates programatically without resorting to internal xmlhttp requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware of it is not possible to capture the output.

If you require unit testing for classic ASP you might have a look at [ajaxed](http://www.ajaxed.org/article/Creating-unit-tests-for-your-asp-application/31/)